# How many times the condition of explicit wait is checked?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In case of implicit wait, if `WebDriver` doesn't find element immediately, it waits for specified time and if element not found after specified time elapses, it throws an exception.

Means in case of implicit wait, `WebDriver` checks element twice(max):

1. Immediately
2. (If immediately not found,) at the end of specified time.

But in case of explicit wait, how often the condition is checked?

I mean if it checks every second for condition to become true/not null or only twice like implicit wait?

Comment: WebDriverWait by default calls the ExpectedCondition every 500 milliseconds until it returns successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default it checks for every 500 milliseconds (i.e. polling).
So from source-code you can see -

> public final static long DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIMEOUT = 500;

```
public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeOutInSeconds) {
    this(driver, new SystemClock(), Sleeper.SYSTEM_SLEEPER, timeOutInSeconds, DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIMEOUT);
}
```

where it internally calls to -

```
protected WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, Clock clock, Sleeper sleeper, long timeOutInSeconds,
      long sleepTimeOut) {
    super(driver, clock, sleeper);
    withTimeout(timeOutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    pollingEvery(sleepTimeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    ignoring(NotFoundException.class);
  }
```